# PYQT5 connect two QSpinBox

Tags: python-2.7, pyqt5, qspinbox

i want know how to connect two QSpinBox with condition when we change the value of one of them the second one changed
i tried this using Qt designer

self.spinA.valueChanged['int'].connect(self.spinB.setValue)

the value is always the same ; i tried to connect label to spinA and use its value to get new value for spinB but i don't know how to do the same to change spinA value based on spinB value
and sorry for my english ; i can explain better with my native language

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Add action to the first spin box for every value changed in the spin box, inside the action change the value of second spin box according to the relation between the values, do same for the second spin box as well below is the sample code.

## importing libraries

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *

import sys

class Window(QMainWindow):

```
def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()

    # setting title
    self.setWindowTitle("Python ")

    # setting geometry
    self.setGeometry(100, 100, 600, 400)

    # calling method
    self.UiComponents()

    # showing all the widgets
    self.show()

    # method for widgets
def UiComponents(self):

    # creating spin box
    self.spin1 = QSpinBox(self)

    # setting geometry to spin box
    self.spin1.setGeometry(100, 100, 150, 40)

    # setting prefix to spin
    self.spin1.setPrefix("Width : ")

    # add action to this spin box
    self.spin1.valueChanged.connect(self.action_spin1)

    # creating another spin box
    self.spin2 = QSpinBox(self)

    # setting geometry to spin box
    self.spin2.setGeometry(300, 100, 150, 40)

    # setting prefix to spin box
    self.spin2.setPrefix("Height : ")

    # add action to this spin box
    self.spin2.valueChanged.connect(self.action_spin2)

# method called after editing finished
def action_spin1(self):

    # getting current value of spin box
    current = self.spin1.value()
    self.spin2.setValue(current)

    # method called after editing finished
def action_spin2(self):
    # getting current value of spin box
    current = self.spin2.value()
    self.spin1.setValue(current)
```

## create pyqt5 app

App = QApplication(sys.argv)

## create the instance of our Window

window = Window()

## start the app

sys.exit(App.exec())

Comment: Thank you i will try it